# SUM data present in a row for a reference in column A and after filtering for a date range (min and max) present in row 3 of my data range A3:Z300

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data range from A1:Z300, the row (A1:Z1) contains dates of a typical month, and the column (A1:A300) contains text (ingredients). I want a formula to sum the data present in the corresponding row of a particular reference (ingredient) in column A (say "Salt") after filtering a given date range, say ">=Today()+1" and "<=today()+7" in row 1.The formula is used to compare data. My data range typically looks: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Formula

```
=SUM(
   FILTER(
     FILTER(B1:Z, A1:A=AA2),
     B1:Z1>=IF(AB2="Any", B1:Z1, AB2),
     B1:Z1<=IF(AC2="Any", B1:Z1, AC2)))
```

### Sample Data

- Formula is in **`AD2`**
- lookup text is in **`AA2`**
- from and to dates are in **`AB2:AC2`** (will also accept **`"Any"`**).

|  | AA | AB | AC | AD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **INGREDIENT** | **FROM** | **TO** | **FORMULA** |
| **2** | Sabut Fennel | 12 Jan 24 | Any | 0.15175 |

### Explantion

1. Filters the range for those rows where the **INGREDIENT** is in Column A and returns an array
2. Then filters that array for those columns where the date is on or after **FROM** and on or before **TO**.
3. Sums the result

Comment: I used the formula, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and guidance. The double-filter function was the solution.

Comment: @SeshadevPanda Glad it worked and welcome to Web Applications! Take the [Tour] and hope to see you around again.